# How to convert string into predefined variable in python

Tags: python

Scenario:

```
variable2 = "value inside the string"

for i in range(1,5):
      x = "variable{0}".format(i)
      print(x)
```

I want the above for loop to print "value inside the string" when i is at 2

Comment: You can't really do that... `variable2` is an identifier, while `"variable2"` is a string value. The name `variable2` does not exist when your program is running; it's replaced with a memory address (not really in the case of Python, and there are Python-specific ways to hack this, but it's not something you should rely on). The runtime has no awareness that something like `variable2`. Why not just use a dictionary or an array?

Comment: Why don’t you use a list? What do you want to happen for each i other than 2? Also please note that a range is created using parentheses, not brackets.

Comment: @Ruslan I wouldn't say the runtime has *no* awareness. There are [**`locals()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) and [**`globals()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you could do that with `globals()`/`locals()` hackery, but I wouldn't recommend it. Instead, use a dictionary:

```
variables = {
    2: "value inside the string",
    # ...
}

for i in range(1,5):
      x = variables[i]  # or variables.get(i, "some default") if values can be missing
      print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access local variables as a dictionary, and then look them up using a string:

```
>>> variable2 = "value inside the string"
>>> locals()['variable2']
'value inside the string'
```

See [**`locals()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals)

Comment: I would say though that this seems a strange thing to be doing, and perhaps there is a better way to solve whatever problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 scenarios here,

1. you want to print something in a particular case,

```
   for i in range(1,5):
        if i == 2:
            #do something
            print(variable2)
```

2. you want multiple variables and print them one after another, in that case using a list would be helpful

```
   variables = ["something1","value inside the string","something2","something3"]
   for i in range(1,5):
     print(variables[i-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using **eval**

variable2 = "value inside the string"

i=2
print(eval("variable{0}".format(i)))

Above print statement will print "value inside the string"